# Serialize nested typescript classes to json

Tags: node.js, json, typescript

I can not serialize a nested set of classes to json:

```
import { readFileSync  } from 'fs'

class Address {
    constructor(
        public readonly street: string,
        public readonly city: string){}
}

class Person {
    constructor(
        public readonly address: Address,
        public readonly name: string){}
}

class School {
    private students = new Map<string, Person>();
    public add(student: Person): School {
        this.students.set(student.name, student);
        return this;
    }
    public toJson(filename: string) {        
    }
}

const p1 = new Person(new Address("5th Ave.", "NYC"), "moish");
const p2 = new Person(new Address("remi", "Boston"), "dave");
const p3 = new Person(new Address("Dart", "Boston"), "uzi");

let school = new School();
school.add(p1).add(p2).add(p3)
console.log(school); // <--- good ! but wrong format 
console.log(JSON.stringify(school)); // doesn't work: {"students":{}}
```

And here is how I compile and run it:

```
% npx tsc --target es2022 --moduleResolution node main.ts
% node main.js                                           
School {
  students: Map(3) {
    'moish' => Person { address: [Address], name: 'moish' },
    'dave' => Person { address: [Address], name: 'dave' },
    'uzi' => Person { address: [Address], name: 'uzi' }
  }
}
{"students":{}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct method name for customizing the value used during an object's JSON serialization is [`toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior).

In your case you just need to provide a serializable data type instead of a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), such as an object. You can use the [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) method on the map's [`entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) iterator method to produce such an object:

```ts
toJSON (): { students: Record<string, Person> } {
  return { students: Object.fromEntries(this.students.entries()) };
}
```

Here's a complete example based on the code you showed in your question:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=23&ssc=19&pln=23&pc=57#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-AwEHk3ZU9bmABmLNu51EV05guxH0AETASBI5arNeohHrFfIAC8yxDW95RHUGk0HTnbpuLVgIBvGq9onRmDazCfEGf05fT52IQbGsaQPh5HQsXj3nTOKKhH8jxAMxtmgAB6UDMG9HlBm9SQMG9eNE1g+DokLZCoLIFAJFgv0A1gINXhDb09AMHCI2jSxFG9IEUBwxCICTSjvUbZs4O9VDYnQsQsInSRixQUsiJIoQcOrWtZyYmicJY2imMXMs2I4qAuMw7C+NHcchP0ES+LEmdvUk3JaL4+SDMsawgA)

```ts
class Address {
  constructor (
    public readonly street: string,
    public readonly city: string,
  ) {}
}

class Person {
  constructor (
    public readonly address: Address,
    public readonly name: string,
  ) {}
}

class School {
  private students = new Map<string, Person>();

  public add (student: Person): School {
    this.students.set(student.name, student);
    return this;
  }

  public toJSON (): { students: Record<string, Person> } {
    return { students: Object.fromEntries(this.students.entries()) };
  }
}

console.clear();
const p1 = new Person(new Address("5th Ave.", "NYC"), "moish");
const p2 = new Person(new Address("remi", "Boston"), "dave");
const p3 = new Person(new Address("Dart", "Boston"), "uzi");

const school = new School();
school.add(p1).add(p2).add(p3);
console.log(JSON.stringify(school)); // {"students":{"moish":{"address":{"street":"5th Ave.","city":"NYC"},"name":"moish"},"dave":{"address":{"street":"remi","city":"Boston"},"name":"dave"},"uzi":{"address":{"street":"Dart","city":"Boston"},"name":"uzi"}}}
```

Compiled JS from the TS Playground:

```js
"use strict";
class Address {
    constructor(street, city) {
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
    }
}
class Person {
    constructor(address, name) {
        this.address = address;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
class School {
    constructor() {
        this.students = new Map();
    }
    add(student) {
        this.students.set(student.name, student);
        return this;
    }
    toJSON() {
        return { students: Object.fromEntries(this.students.entries()) };
    }
}
console.clear();
const p1 = new Person(new Address("5th Ave.", "NYC"), "moish");
const p2 = new Person(new Address("remi", "Boston"), "dave");
const p3 = new Person(new Address("Dart", "Boston"), "uzi");
const school = new School();
school.add(p1).add(p2).add(p3);
console.log(JSON.stringify(school)); // {"students":{"moish":{"address":{"street":"5th Ave.","city":"NYC"},"name":"moish"},"dave":{"address":{"street":"remi","city":"Boston"},"name":"dave"},"uzi":{"address":{"street":"Dart","city":"Boston"},"name":"uzi"}}}
```

---

Reference for the utility type `Record<Keys, Type>`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type

Comment: can you explain the returned type of `toJSON`? I am not sure I understand it

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74544306/serialize-nested-typescript-classes-to-json/74544642?noredirect=1#comment131587682_74544642) @OrenIshShalom I updated the answer with a link to the utility type used. The return type is an object with a property `students` which is an object with string keys and `Person` values.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native support for `Map` to JSON serialization. But you can override `toJSON` method.

```js
class School {
  students = new Map();

  add(student) {
    this.students.set(student.name, student)
    return this;
  }

  toJSON() {
    return {
      students: Object.fromEntries(this.students)
    }
  }
}

class Student {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}

const school = new School().add(new Student('A')).add(new Student('B')).add(new Student('C'))

console.log(JSON.stringify(school))
```